# I can share some files, but others lock me out. Why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm pretty new to Google Script but I'm working on a kind of Master Library that includes links to all important files across multiple departments in my company.

Some of the files are not properly shared, so when someone submits a new link to the Library I was hoping to change the sharing access and permissions.

To test my new code I had another employee create a private file and share it with me. I was able to successfully change the access to DOMAIN and the permission to EDIT.

Then I tried to add another file, this time in a folder that was already shared. The owner of the file got a message that I had "restricted access" to the file, and it disappeared from my "Shared with me" folder. Not only can I no longer access the file, I can't even find it via Search.

Why am I able to change sharing for one file but not the other? And why do I no longer have access to the file?

Thanks for any help, suggestions, or information.

```
var my_file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
my_file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

Comment: Google Drive? Team Drive? Gsuite?

Comment: We are using Gsuite; sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Just a quick update: I experimented with some more files and got wildly different results. I was able to change sharing for some files, some files gave me an access error, and the sharing changed for some files from being accessible to anyone in the company, to a list of like 30 people. NO idea why that happened.

I had a quick meeting with the Head of IT and he suggested moving everything to Team Drive AND my code should leave sharing alone. Too many variables for it to work reliably...